# How to make a copy from an already created survey in Survey 123

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I currently have a survey in Survey 123 in the web version, now I want to create a copy to make just some changes, and be able to edit on the web version. I did it in the desktop version Survey 123 connect, but when I uploaded the survey to the web version I cannot edit.

Comment: If you copy it using Survey123 Connect, then you can make edits in Survey123 Connect and re-publish it from Survey123 Connect to update it with changes (as many times as you like), but you would have to make the changes in Survey123 Connect (using Excel to edit the XLSForm file).  Sorry, I don't know much about doing it via the web interface.